# What is formed when hydrogen peroxide reacts with titanium?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, everyday-chemistry, cleaning

I just got night contact lenses, and you are supposed to use a "one-step" cleaning solution to clean it over a period of six hours. At the bottom of the lenses case, there is a "titanium plate neutralizer", which causes the liquid to bubble. What is this gas?

Edit: it was platinum, not titanium

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hydrogen peroxide will damage your eye tissue; that's why there are enzymes in our cells actually to catalyze the conversion of $HOOH$ to water and oxygen gas. The enzymes are actually contained in *peroxisomes* (name is self-explanatory).* The neutralizer serves the same function of catalyzing the otherwise relatively slow decomposition of $HOOH$ into water and oxygen gas; hydrogen peroxide will decompose in the presence of light and that's why bottles of hydrogen perioxide are opaque - generally black or brown (but not transparent like bottles of <strike>which</strike> *witch* hazel or isopropyl alcohol). I have seen platinum used as a catalyst in contact cleaning solutions but I suppose titanium can be used as well.

*Edit: peroxisomes actually create $HOOH$ upon catabolism of cell by-products but can also break down its own toxic byproduct.

Comment: What happens to the platinum after it is used for a certain amount of time? The box says to replace the neutralizer disc after 30 days. Also, what happens to HOOH when it decomposes (what results)?

Comment: You get water and oxygen gas when the HOOH dissolves. The platinum is actually consumed through HOOH decomposition. I've found out the hard way (from using my contact neutralization case for way over 30 days ... ouch!)

Comment: What does the platinum become after the chemical reaction? (just curious)

Comment: So if after 30 days, I take out the neutralizer somehow and slice off the outer layer of platinum (which would be very hard indeed), would the reaction still work?

Comment: I'm thinking there is a very, very thin layer of platinum on there so if you scrape off what was consumed, then you won't have much left. Also now I'm unclear on the catalysis of the decomposition of HOOH by Pt. By definition, a catalyst is NOT consumed in a reaction, but by all empirical means, it appears that Pt is consumed. Also, HOOH can be both reduced and oxidized, depending on pH. I'm thinking that HOOH is oxidized because that's when it creates oxygen gas. When it is reduced, it produces reactive radicals (not good for your cells!).If HOOH is oxidized then PT must be reduced; gains e-

Comment: If it were pure platinum, would the electrons from the inside go to the outside to participate in the reaction?

Comment: No clue; I'm lost. Better consult someone better versed in redox chemistry than I am.

Comment: @Jason The decomposition of hydrogen peroxide is a disproportionation reaction, hence one oxygen is reduced and one is oxidised. The platinum/ titanium disk should not be compromised by this reaction as they are only catalysts. There might/will be reaction paths (sideways) that wear down every catalyst. Depending on the thickness of the Pt layer is might be oxidised by air. Mechanical forces might also be at work. And there could be many more effects at play...

Comment: If I was cynical I would think the neutraliser is consumed on purpose at a rate that 50 doses of cleaning solution will consume.  I also suspect that using your own platinum catalyst (thin and cheap loop of wire from reputable manufacturing jeweller) would last forever.